# heatmap not representing data accurately

Tags: r, heatmap

Below is a sample of my data set, which is simply 14 columns and about 6500 rows, filled with 1's and 0's. Download my entire data set [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IVVApFe0lv6Q7TlPPwcjKIOUgmDopKc2).

```
Row C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9  C10 C11 C12 C13 C14
2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1
3   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1
4   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1
5   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1
6   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0
7   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1
8   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1
9   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1
```

Column 8 has 13 zeros, but these are not represented in the heatmap.

```
Row    C1   C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9  C10 C11 C12 C13 C14
5011    1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   1
5801    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0
5803    1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0
5809    1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0
5812    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0
5813    1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0
5815    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0
5817    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0
5818    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0
5823    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0
5826    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0
6435    1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   1
6436    1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   1
```

How can I edit my code to have these 13 zeros represented in the heatmap as a white line like the other columns?

**heatmap code**

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(openxlsx)


# Read in dataset
df <- read.xlsx("data set.xlsx", sheet = 1)

# Set as integer matrix
m <- as.matrix(df[, -1])

#Create colors
greyblack <- c("grey", "black")
pal <- colorRampPalette(greyblack)(100)

# Create heatmap
heatmap(m, Rowv = NA, Colv = NA, scale="none", col = pal, ylab="Records", main="Data Completeness")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem of resolution.  Each of these missing rows in col 8 are a single pixel wide.  Column 1 also has zeroes that don't appear (rows 2811 and 3639), and the other columns have plenty of single-row (pixel) spaces of missing data that don't appear.  When I cut the dataset down to a small area around one of the zeros in C8, they appear:

```
smalldf <- df[5009:5013,]
smallm <- as.matrix(smalldf[,-1])
heatmap(smallm, Rowv = NA, Colv = NA, scale="none", col = pal, ylab="Records", main="Data Completeness")
```

[Image: When df is cut down to the area around one of the zeros on column 8, the white line shows up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNdYC.png)

If you really want to show these 1-row-missing data in the heatmap, I would suggest replacing the adjacent 1s with zeroes.  (ie, 1 zero becomes 1 zero above it and 1 zero below it.). A quick and dirty way to do that for one column:

```
> idx <- which(df$Column.8 == 0)
> df$Column.8[idx-2] <- 0
> df$Column.8[idx-1] <- 0
> df$Column.8[idx+1] <- 0
> df$Column.8[idx+2] <- 0

> m <- as.matrix(df[, -1])
> heatmap(m, Rowv = NA, Colv = NA, scale="none", col = pal, ylab="Records", main="Data Completeness")
```

This causes the lines to show up at least, although it appears as if there are only 2-3 discrete holes rather than 8 individual, tiny holes:

[Heatmap with 'resampled' column 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxhXU.png)

I'm not sure if this is a good way to do it, because I'm not sure what you're using this data/heatmap for.  If it's just visualization of where the missing data is, then this should help.  (And you may want to do the same thing for other columns)

Comment: thanks. However, I am receiving the following error: `Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, Column.8, value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 8310`.